# How to show what level of permission a group or user has to a site?

Tags: 2007, development, permissions, security, site

In SharePoint 2007 when you go to a site and view advanced permissions *(Site Actions - Site Settings - Modify All Site Settings - Advanced Permissions)* you are presented with a page that has a table of all the users and groups that can access that site as well as their permission level.

I would like to replicate that as a console output (ultimately my goal is to sync this to a database regularly for audit purposes, but for the sake of a proof, the console).

Unfortunately I don't know enough about SharePoint programming, and this is where I've got to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string siteCollection = "http://dev/re/ad/wf";
    string version = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)).GetName().Version.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] SharePoint Permissions started with version '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), version);

    using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(siteCollection).OpenWeb())
    {
        foreach(SPRoleAssignment role in oWebsite.RoleAssignments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Member ID: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), role.Member.ID);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Member Name: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), role.Member.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Member Parent: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), role.Parent);

            foreach(SPRoleDefinition rd in role.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Role Def Base Permissions: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), rd.BasePermissions);
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Role Def Type: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), rd.Type);
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Role Description: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), rd.Description);

            }


            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        }
    }

}
```

How should I be approaching this? I'm concerned that the code above will be limited in just showing groups, I'd also like to show users that have direct access to a location, and ultimately, their permission level as well. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this one with the following proof:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string siteCollection = "http://marlindev/re/ad/wf";
    string version = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)).GetName().Version.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] SharePoint Permissions started with version '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), version);

    using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(siteCollection).OpenWeb())
    {
        foreach(SPRoleAssignment role in oWebsite.RoleAssignments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Member ID: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), role.Member.ID);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Member Name: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), role.Member.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Member Type: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), role.Member.GetType());

            foreach(SPRoleDefinition rd in role.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Role Def Type: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), rd.Type);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        }
    }

}
```